# a regex to add a period inbetween numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

im in need of help regarding a regex,
i have lines that look like this

1995

80

100

83

3
Etc

I need them to becomes

1.9.9.5

8.0

1.0.0

8.3

3

and i dont know how the single numbers would turn out with a regex to do this

I dont have experience with regex, which is why im posting here, any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: (\d)(\d)  replace with  $1.$2

Comment: @Ali: no, this will not work. You can't match the same digit twice.

Comment: Diddnt really work, didnt add period in between all numbers

Comment: then run twice ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Find what: (?=\d\d+)(.) 
Replace with: \1\.
```

uses a non consuming group to first assert that the line has more than one digit,
then captures each digit and replaces it with the digit followed by a .

for the last digit in a number with more than one ie `234`, it fails the assertion because the regex engine has already parsed `234` and so treats it as `4`.

Comment: Works pretty good, all i gotta do is remove the slashes and looks perfect, thank you

Comment: my bad, had the extra slash because I had moved it from the s/find/replace/g syntax

Answer (score 2):

Use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to do such job.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\d)(?=\d)`
- Replace with: `.`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=    : start lookbehind, make sure before we have
  \d    : a digit
)       : end lookbehind
(?=     : start lookahead, make sure after we have
  \d    : a digit
)       : end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
a dot, that will be inserted between 2 digits.
```

**Result for given example:**

```
1.9.9.5
8.0
1.0.0
8.3
3
```